# Sending html page as reponse to axios call using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I am making an axios call to check for an existing JWT token. If it exists I would like to render my admin panel else redirect to the login page.
By now I have my backend like this:

```
//The admin panel page. check for valid JWT token, otherwise prompt to login page
router.use("/", (req,res)=>{
    var token = req.headers.authorization;
  if (token && token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
    // Remove Bearer from string
    token = token.slice(7, token.length);
  }
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, "secret", (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname , '../views/login.html'));
      } else {
        User.findOne({
          _id: decoded.id
        }).then(function (user) {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname , '../views/admin.html'));
        })
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname , '../views/login.html'));
  }
});
```

Which is working fine but in my front end the result I get in axios is as an object and the page is not shown but the response is stored in memory.

```
Object { data: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n
```

Whole html document i send is in the data field of the reponse.

Here is my axios call:

```
function onPage(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('token')){
    const Url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/";
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
  };
  axios.post(Url, {}, config).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {});
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Whole html document i send is in the data field of the reponse.

You can do that by using [the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) or the library of your choice that wraps the DOM in an easier API. For instance, `document.write(response.data)` would do it, because after the main parsing of the page, `document.write` does an implicit `document.open` which wipes out the page and replaces it with the string.

That said, if you want to do a POST and replace the page with the resulting full HTML, you may just want a standard `form` element, as that's their default behavior.

Comment: I know that, the things is how can i load the data which is html code in the current page ?

Comment: @KristijanStefanoski - I've replaced the answer.